# T/F: a smooth function that grows faster than any linear function grows faster than $x^{1+\epsilon}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Prove or find a counterexample to the claim that a smooth function that grows faster than any linear function grows faster than $x^{1+\epsilon}$ for some $\epsilon>0$.

My attempt: I understand that the first part of the problem claims $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{g(x)}{kx} = \infty, \forall k>0$. We want to show, then, that $\exists \epsilon >0$ and constant $l>0$ such that $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{g(x)}{lx^{1+\epsilon}} = \infty$.

I've tried using the definition of limits, but I get stuck trying to bound the function $\frac{1}{x^\epsilon}$. Also, I've tried using L'Hopital's rule to no avail. Any ideas?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Try $g(x) = x \ln x$.

Comment: The way to approach this is to find a function that does not grow as fast as $x^{\varepsilon}$ for any $\varepsilon$ then just multiply it by $x$, as per @OpenBall's answer.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** It is *false*. Find a counterexample.

**Followup hint:** *(place your mouse on the hidden text to show it)*

> The function $f\colon(0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = x\ln x$ is such a counterexample.

**Followup followup hint:** *(pretty much the solution, with some details to fill in; place your mouse on the hidden text to show it)*

> For any $a>0$, $\frac{x\ln x}{a x} = \frac{1}{a}\ln x \xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{} \infty$. However, for any fixed $\epsilon > 0$, $$\frac{x\ln x}{x^{1+\epsilon}} = \frac{\ln x}{x^\epsilon}=\frac{1}{\epsilon}\frac{\ln(x^\epsilon)}{x^\epsilon} = \frac{1}{\epsilon}\frac{\ln t}{t}$$ for $t=x^\epsilon \xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}\infty$.